# Azure Pipeline- Copy files to distribution folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am new to DevOps.  I have a release that builds my solution and creates a zip file of the files that I want to deploy to a distribution folder which is a shared folder on my local machine.  The last step in my pipeline copies (supposedly) to a location in my repo but nothing shows up.

[Create zip task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpwAX.png)

[Copy to repo task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8px8.png)

When I go to repo in DevOps and look for the folder it is empty.  All I want to do is have the zip file copied to a local folder on my machine so that users can pick up the new release of the software and install.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Share your complete YAML pipeline. Also note that the "Copy Files" task is **not** doing what you think it's doing; it's for copying files to a different location *within the pipeline agent's working directory*. It's **not** copying **anything** into your repo. In fact, you **do not** want to put binaries such as zip files in your repo under any circumstances, as it will bloat your repo and quickly render it unusable.

Answer (score 0):

`Build.Repository.LocalPath` is a path of a cloned repo on your build machine. Do you use this folder as a shared folder?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

> Build.Repository.LocalPath - The local path on the agent where your
> source code files are downloaded. For example: c:\agent_work\1\s

That`s not clear which version of DevOps you are using: Azure DevOps Services or DevOps Server.

1. For Azure DevOps Services, you may use:

   1. Cloud build agent. In this case, it is not recommended to copy from the cloud to your local machine.
   2. Self-hosted build agent in your local network. Use copy to the artifacts folder ([Copy Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)) and then publish it to your network-shared folder ([Publish Pipeline Artifacts task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) `artifactType = filepath`, `fileSharePath = \\server\folderName`).
   3. Self-hosted build agent on your local machine. Just use the direct path to your shared folder to copy files.
2. For Azure DevOps Server:

   1. I think, you should use the 1.2 option.